# Linearizing a nonlinear differential equation

Tags: nonlinear-system, linearization

So I have a nonlinear equation which is $m\ddot{x}+(b\dot{x})^3+kx-u=0$ that I want to linearize. Can anyone help me do this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Start by writing your question using MathJax, then nondimensionalize the equation of interest and show here what you end up with.

Comment: Also you say linearize; where are you linearizing it? Around $(x,\dot{x})=(0,0)$ or what? Also are any of the parameters small?